# Sentence with correct use of "speed"

Tags: word-usage

What is the best way to say that some exercise needs needs to be done with consideration of time required for its completion. In other words, the kind of exercise when time for completion is one of the factors and someone is there with a stopwatch to control how fast you do it.
I need to say something like "This exercise is done ...." How? At speed? For speed? Considering speed?

Comment: I would suggest saying "against the clock" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/against-the-clock

Comment: Yes,but in generally the adjective/adverb is fast.

Comment: @Lambie, for this the adverb quickly would be more appropriate, as it relates to doing something in a short period of time rather than at a high velocity. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/fast-quick-or-quickly ... for british speakers, anyway.

Comment: @JavaLatte It depends. This exercise should be done as fast as possible, as quickly as possible=same thing in all Englishes.  Against the clock really means in 10 minutes, in 15 minutes etc. and also is the same in all Englishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This exercise should be timed" is good for an exercise with a stopwatch. It implies both the precise time consideration and the speed.

> measure the time taken by (a process or activity, or a person doing it).
>
> "we were timed and given certificates according to our speed"

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/time (scroll down to Verb)